# Style title of link

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, title

I am struggling to style a title of a link, with jQuery-mobile. Every link is a player. Every player has a special ability. This is what I would like to be displayed when the user hovers over this player. I've tried many code samples, but none of them worked. My last attempt lies in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/aLrrk997/).

Here is the link's markup (HTML):

```
<li class="ui-btn-icon-left"><a class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Promising goalkeeper" href="#"><span>L_Oikonomo</span></a></li>
```

Below is the CSS for the tooltip (without vendor prefixes):

```
/* tooltip body text */
 .tooltip:hover:before {
    display:block;
    background:#eee;
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(255, 205, 205, 0.9), rgba(228, 230, 230, 0.9));
    content:attr(data-tooltip);    /* this link attribute contains tooltip text */
    position:absolute;
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
    bottom:20px;    /* ensure link text is visible under tooltip */
    right:0px;    /* align both tooltip and link right edges */
    width:11em;    /* a reasonable width to wrap tooltip text */
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    border:2px solid rgba(204, 153, 153, 0.9);
    border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow:-2px -2px 2px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
}
/* styles shared by both triangles */
 .tooltip:hover span:before, .tooltip:hover span:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border-style:solid;
}
/* outer triangle: for border */
 .tooltip:hover span:before {
    bottom:5px;    /* value = tooltip:hover:before (border-width*2)+1 */
    right:40px;    /* controls horizontal position */
    border-width:16px 16px 0;    /* top, right-left, bottom */
    border-color:rgba(204, 153, 153, 0.9) transparent;    /* top/bottom, right-left (lazy becasue bottom is 0) */
}
/* inner triangle: for fill */
 .tooltip:hover span:after {
    bottom:8px;    /* value = tooltip:before (border-width*2) */
    right:42px;    /* above 'right' value + 2 */
    border-width:14px 14px 0;    /* 2 less than above */
    border-color:rgba(225, 238, 238, 0.95) transparent;    /* tweak opacity by eye/eyedropper to obscure outer triangle colour */
}
```

Is is it possible to get this working? 
If not, do you have anything else in mind to style the title of the link?

Comment: An alternative could be using https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Thanks for the info @leo.fcx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing with your code seems to be partly because of the `.tooltip:before` pseudo-element being used elsewhere (again probably by the library). As you are already using the jQuery mobile library, it might be better for you to look at [jQuery UI's tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

If you don't want to use the library, the following changes should be done to fix the problem and get a styled tooltip (or title) displayed when moving the mouse over the anchor element:

- The library is currently adding a `overflow: hidden` to the anchor element. If this is not removed the tooltip will not show up fully as the overflowing part would be hidden.

  ```
  .ui-page-theme-a .ui-block-a a.ui-btn {
      overflow: visible;
  }
  ```
- Use the `span` tag to create the tooltip instead of the `a` tag (because as mentioned earlier, the `a` tag's pseudo-element seems to be already used).

  ```
  <li class="ui-btn-icon-left">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Promising goalkeeper">L_Oikonomo</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  ```
- Add `position: relative` to the `span` element as we need to position the tooltip absolutely with respect to it.

  ```
  .tooltip {
      position: relative;
  }
  ```
- Add the code to display the tooltip while moving the mouse over the anchor. This is pretty much the same as your original code with the exception of a few minimal changes. `z-index` is added so that the tooltip gets displayed above the link text.

  ```
  a:hover .tooltip:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: attr(data-tooltip);
      bottom: 2em; /* ensure link text is visible under tooltip */
      right:0px; /* align both tooltip and link right edges */
      height: 2em;
      width: 11em;
      background:linear-gradient(rgba(255, 205, 205, 0.9), rgba(228, 230, 230, 0.9));
      content:attr(data-tooltip); /* this link attribute contains tooltip text */
      font-size:0.9em;
      color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.9);
      text-align:center;
      padding:4px;
      border:2px solid rgba(204, 153, 153, 0.9);
      border-radius:6px;
      box-shadow:-2px -2px 2px rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
      z-index: 1;
  }
  ```
- The below code is for the triangle at the bottom. I have used the `transform: rotate(45deg)` method to create the triangle instead of the border method because we have only one spare pseudo-element. The extra gradient is required because we need the triangle to be colored only for half its size.

  ```
  a:hover .tooltip:after {
      content:"";
      position:absolute;
      bottom: calc(2em - 8px);
      right:42px;
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, #eee 50%);
      border: 1px solid rgba(204, 153, 153, 0.9);
      border-width: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      z-index: 2;
  }
  ```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLrrk997/1/)

Comment: You have helped me so many times...thank you so much, God bless you!

Comment: Harry, I just saw that in a mobile, the title gets cut off from the left. Can we do something about it? http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/aLrrk997/2/

Comment: @gsamaras: Does changing the `right` properties (of both `:before` and `:after`) to `left` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLrrk997/3/) help?

Comment: Now it will cut off from the right. I will look into it later. ;)

Comment: @gsamaras: You mean the boxes are same width as viewport? If yes then you would probably need to reduce the `width` to something manageable (or) use negative positioning like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLrrk997/4/) to fit it within the box.